# How to avoid anthropomorphic language when talking about AI?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, natural-language-processing

In my opinion we should not talk about chatgtp or similar AIs as if they have agency, because that will lead to people thinking these programs are real intelligent beings.

So I think we should avoid phrases like: ChatGTP said..,..thinks,.."it" / "he/she",... did this/did that, and so on.

Is there a general way how to avoid anthropomorphization? What words are to be avoided? How can we talk differently about these programs while still being concise?

Comment: I don't think I understand what your question is, or how this is a matter of computer science.  If you want to avoid anthropomorphization, don't use those words.  What else is there to say?  What is a "general way"?  I don't think you're going to get someone to give you an exhaustive list of words to avoid, and I don't think that is in scope for this site, and it sounds very broad.  This site is for technical questions about computer science, not for questions about the English language.